# Reshuffle values in columns of panda dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, sklearn-pandas

Panda dataframe

```
|   | col A |   
|---|-------|
| 0 | A     |   
| 1 | B     |  
| 2 | C     |
```

Expected output (After re-shuffling)

```
|   | col A |   
|---|-------|
| 0 | B     |   
| 1 | C     |  
| 2 | A     |
```

As shown, I **do not** want to reshuffle the (index,value) entire pair but want to reshuffle the values in the columns (after reshuffling values in colA will have new index)

Does any know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the easiest way is to use `np.random.permutation`

```
>>> import pandas as pd, numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':list('ABCDEF')})
>>> df
  colA
0    A
1    B
2    C
3    D
4    E
5    F
```

Then

```
>>> df['colA'] = np.random.permutation(df.colA)
>>> df
  colA
0    D
1    A
2    F
3    B
4    C
5    E
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

`np.shuffle` operates in place.

```
np.random.shuffle(df.colA)
```

will shuffle the array of values in `colA`
to check

```
df

  colA
0    C
1    E
2    A
3    F
4    D
5    B
```